# From looking at the size of the matrix, how do find the domain and codomain of the transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example, if I had a matrix $a$ of size 3x2, how would you find its domain and codomain of the transformation $Ta(x) = Ax$. What does the equation mean?

Comment: Usually the domain and codomain have to be defined for the function. If not, you can take, for example, domain $\Bbb R^2$ and codomain $\Bbb R^3$, but that is just a example.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix over $F$, then the linear transformation $T$ associated with $A$ is a map from $F^n$ to $F^m$.

Comment: What does F represent?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson, F denotes the underlying field. For example It can be the real line R or the complex plane C.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Would it be considered the abstract representation of both the domain and the co-domain?